# Проблемы с динамической памятью

Tags: c

**В приведённом ниже коде не получается использовать динамическую память.**

Я выделяю указателю динамическую память под `max` элементов , далее пытаюсь записать в часть памяти несколько значений для дальнейшего сравнения. Например

```
*parr = 2;
*(parr + 1) = 3; 
*(parr + 2) = 5;
```

Но указатель не переходит выше по элементам , а пишет всё в один (точнее переписывает значение в этом же элементе)

```
long* parry(nullptr); // пустой указатель.
long trial = 5; // кандидат на простое число.
int count = 3; // кол-во простых чисел (объявленных)
int found = 0; // признак обнаружения простого числа.
int max2 = 0; // определяем кол-во простых чисел

cout << "enter the numbers of digits: ";
cin >> max2;

parry = new long[max2]; // выделяю память под max2 элементов.
//
// собственно проблема на следующей строке.
*parry = 2; // пишу в первый элемент 2.
*(parry + 1) = 3; // пишу во второй элемент 3.
*(parry + 2) = 5; // пишу в 3-ий 5.

do {
    trial += 2;
    found = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        found = (trial % *(parry + i)) == 0;

        if (found)
            break;
    }
    if(found == 0)
        *(parry + count++) = found;

} while (count < max2);

for (int i = 0; i < max2; ++i)
{
    if (i % 5 == 0)
        cout << endl;
    cout << setw(6) << *(parry + i);
}
delete[] parry;
parry = nullptr;
cout << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://ideone.com/iR5qyM всё работает. Сделайте минимальный пример, демонстрирующий ошибку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Измените код

```
if(found == 0)
    *(parry + count++) = found;
```

на следующий

```
 if(found == 0)
     *(parry + count++) = trial;
```

У вас происходит заполнение нулями и при следующих итерациях идёт деление на ноль вот тут

```
found = (trial % *(parry + i)) == 0;
```

Работающий [пример](https://ideone.com/DLORck)

Comment: спасибо , простите за мою ошибку , видимо я запарился)